# Definition of pointwise convergence for a difference scheme (numerical PDEs)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, pointwise-convergence

I am currently reading *Numerical Partial Differential Equations: Finite Difference Methods* by J.W. Thomas and I'm trying to get a better grasp of the following definition on page 42.

> **Definition 2.2.1.** A difference scheme $L_k^n u_k^n = G_k^n$ approximating the partial differential equation $\mathcal{L} v = F$ is called *pointwise convergent* if for any $x$ and $t$, as $(k \Delta x, (n+1)\Delta t)$ converges to $(x,t)$, $u_k^n$ converges to $v(x,t)$ as $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ converge to $0$.

In this context $v:[0,L] \times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ denotes the true solution and $u_k^n$ denotes the numerical approximation of $v(k \Delta x, n \Delta t)$.

**My questions.**

1. How am I to interpret "as $(k\Delta x, (n+1)\Delta t)$ converges to $(x,t)$" ? For a fixed $(x,t)$, the values of $k$ and $n$ must depend on $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$, so I find this sentence confusing. My attempts to paraphrase it are below, but I am not sure if I'm interpreting things correctly.
2. In a remark on page 44, the author makes the following remark comparing the above definition with a definition of convergence in terms of norms (definition 2.2.2):

> It must be made clear how Definition 2.2.2 differs from Definition 2.2.1. Using Definition 2.2.1, the rate at which $u_k^n$ converges to $v(x,t)$ (rate in terms of $\Delta x \to 0$ and $\Delta t \to 0$) can vary greatly for different values of $x$. In fact, Definition 2.2.1 would allow for a scheme to converge for some values of $(x,t)$ and not others...

The last sentence does not make sense to me. How could a pointwise convergent numerical scheme not converge for some values of $(x,t)$? Perhaps the author made a typo, and was actually referring to Definition 2.2.2?

---

Here are my attempts to interpret and paraphrase Definition 2.2.1:

---

**Definition 1.** The scheme $L_k^n u_k^n = G_k^n$ is *pointwise convergent* at $(x,t) \in [0,L] \times [0,T]$ if, for any sequence of discretization parameters $((\Delta x_m, \Delta t_m))_{m=1}^{\infty}$ converging to $(0,0)$, and any sequence of lattice points $((k_m, n_m))_{m=1}^{\infty}$ satisfying

1. $0 \leq k_m \leq \lfloor L/\Delta x_m \rfloor \; \text{ and } 0 \leq n_m \leq \lfloor T/\Delta t_m \rfloor$ for all $m$, and
2. $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} (k_m \Delta x_m, n_m \Delta t_m) = (x,t)$,

we have
$$\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} u(k_m \Delta x_m, n_m \Delta t_m) = v(x,t).$$

The scheme is *pointwise convergent* if it is pointwise convergent at every $(x,t)$ in $D$.

---

**Definition 2.** A difference scheme $L_k^n u_k^n = G_k^n$ approximating the partial differential equation $\mathcal{L} v = F$ is a *pointwise convergent* scheme if for each pair of discretization parameters $\Delta x, \Delta t$ and each pair $(k,n)$ such that $0 \leq k \leq \lfloor L/\Delta x \rfloor$ and $0 \leq n \leq \lfloor T/\Delta t \rfloor$, there exists a constant $C_{k,n}$ independent of $\Delta x, \Delta t$ such that

$$ |u_k^n - v(k \Delta x, n \Delta t)| \leq C_{k,n} (\Delta x + \Delta t).   $$

And if the last definition is correct (or almost correct), I'm not sure whether the constant $C_{k,n}$ should be allowed to depend on $k$ and $n$, or if it should be independent of all parameters. If the latter, then the definition would seem to be a type of uniform convergence, which is stronger than Definition 2.2.1...

Comment: For each $k\leq n$, $k\Delta x$ represents a grid point of a (presumably) equally spaced discretization of the intevral $[0,L]$. Any point $x\in [0,L]$ can be found to be between two grid points: for some $k\leq n-1$, we have $k\Delta x \leq x\leq (k+1)\Delta x$. If the grids are equally spaced, the natural choice of each sub interval's length is $\Delta x = L/n$. So we can write this as a sequence. For each $n$ find $k_n$ such that $x$ is in $[x_{k_n}, x_{k_{n+1}}]$. Set $y_n = x_{k_n}$. Then $y_{n}\to x$ as $n\to \infty$ because $|x-x_{k_n}|\leq \Delta_n=L/n\to 0$. Right?